# Variable Transformation to find Regression Parameters

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, nonlinear-regression

I want to solve a nonlinear regression model $y=\alpha*\exp(\beta)$ using a linear regression model through variable transformation. Simple question up-front: Can I use log transformation even though some of my data (in Y) is negative?

Is there a way to find out which transformation to use for a certain model? I have a data set of two variables without any knowledge of what they stand for.

***Update*** the goal is to find the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of the regression model above, using a linear regression. Therefore I need to transform the model into a linear one. 
The data set contains only 99 entries for X and Y and can be found here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M6kllETfEF7m-tT-1EG3QChuNXufeh_C

Comment: If $y$ changes sign in your data, the model makes no sense. It forces $$\mathrm{sgn}(y_i) = \mathrm{sgn}(\alpha) \quad \forall\ i$$

Comment: What is your goal? If you don't know anything about the processes generating these variables you should usually use non-parametric approaches such as generalized additive models.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data, or if the data set is small add it to the question?

Comment: @AlexR The model can make sense even when $y$ changes sign, if we assume non-multiplicative errors.  For instance, $$y_i=\alpha \exp(\beta x_i) + \varepsilon_i$$ with $\varepsilon_i$ iid Normal$(0,\sigma^2)$ errors can produce such sign changes, especially when some  $\beta x_i\ll 0.$

Comment: @whuber You‘re right. I automagically assumed a multiplicative error term. OP should specify the assumed error structure.

Comment: Re the update: First note that there is, up to a linear transformation, a unique way to transform the *expected response* so that the regression is linear: take the log. Next, please do not confuse *linear regression,* in its usual sense of the conditional expectation of the response varying linearly with the regressor $x,$ with some particular *procedure* to estimate a linear regression, such as Ordinary Least Squares. The crux of the matter seems to be that you cannot apply OLS directly by transforming the response. So don't even try--use an appropriate method instead, such as fitting a GLM.

Comment: If it is of any use to you, when I directly fit your data to the equation "y = a * exp(bx)" with no transform, I get parameter values of a =  1.7423978267794393E-01 and b =  4.1413585384216617E-01 with R-squared of 0.902 and RMSE of 0.874

Comment: My answer supports the results of @James Phillips.

Comment: @PhiLipp What is the interpretation from a business perspective / measurement of a negative value? Your model cannot be linearised with a sign change as-is. Perhaps you need a Generalised Linear Model with some non-normal error term or maybe something entirely different needs to be done. All in all we need some context as to what the values _mean_ in order to suggest meaningful modelling approaches.

Comment: @AlexR I agree that substantive context would help mightily but OP states "two variables without any knowledge of what they stand for" so it's not even clear that there could be a business perspective. It does seem unusual that exponential growth as a pattern goes with some negative values for the response. We can't even rule out that they are fake data with additive errors. That said, a GLM with normal family works fine, although that doesn't rule out other versions working even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the 100 (not 99) observations in a display that might be more convenient for some people.

```
  x      y 
  0   .045
 .1   1.55
 .2    .14
 .3   1.03
 .4  1.107
 .5  1.547
 .6  -.484
 .7  1.152
 .8   .499
 .9  -.796
  1  1.064
1.1  -.626
1.2  1.283
1.3  -.725
1.4   .824
1.5  1.005
1.6  -.089
1.7   .165
1.8  1.807
1.9  -.453
  2  1.331
2.1  1.514
2.2   .795
2.3   .782
2.4   .351
2.5  1.916
2.6  1.179
2.7  1.933
2.8  1.305
2.9  1.872
  3   .611
3.1  1.834
3.2   .967
3.3  2.203
3.4  -.063
3.5  -.321
3.6   .704
3.7  -.463
3.8   .951
3.9   .042
  4   .895
4.1  2.208
4.2  2.037
4.3   .466
4.4   1.59
4.5    .61
4.6  1.461
4.7  -.179
4.8   .213
4.9   .244
  5  1.522
5.1   .703
5.2    .69
5.3   .202
5.4  3.028
5.5   .676
5.6   .821
5.7   .857
5.8   3.25
5.9  1.351
  6  3.084
6.1  1.059
6.2  3.315
6.3  2.688
6.4  3.625
6.5  3.116
6.6  3.667
6.7  2.079
6.8  1.555
6.9  2.616
  7  2.782
7.1  4.467
7.2  2.519
7.3  3.066
7.4  3.971
7.5  3.746
7.6  4.913
7.7  5.246
7.8  3.463
7.9  3.782
  8  4.089
8.1   3.64
8.2  5.278
8.3  5.663
8.4  6.046
8.5  7.148
8.6   5.78
8.7  6.801
8.8  6.536
8.9  5.963
  9   8.13
9.1  8.791
9.2  6.489
9.3  7.389
9.4  8.787
9.5  9.722
9.6  9.745
9.7   9.37
9.8  10.71
9.9 10.032
```

The evident issue here is the 10 negative values of `y`. But no matter: the data are otherwise very well behaved and nonlinear least squares and generalized linear model with log link and Gaussian family return practically the same predictions. (I have no dogma against different set-ups, but there is no need for a transformation. A standard pitfall in comparing data and fitted curve is to forget to judge differences vertically, which is much of the point of the plots of residual versus fitted.)

[image]

The portfolio above is top line: nonlinear least squares; bottom line generalized linear model. A separate analysis confirms that the predictions are very close (biggest absolute difference is about $10^{-6}$). The errors look very much additive, not multiplicative.

Comment: Excellent analysis, my professional compliments.

Comment: +1.  A diagnostic plot of the absolute deviance residuals (against the log predicted value) in the GLM suggests some mild heteroscedasticity, with the SD of the response near $X=10$ being only about half that near $X=2.$  Otherwise the GLM is a nice fit.

Comment: Thanks for the positive comments. You have to strain to see _convincing_ evidence of heteroscedasticity given fewer observations for large $y$.

Comment: I am impressed by how similar the two models are. I appreciate the help, the answer and comments help me a lot! I do think that my Professor created the negative Y-values solely to make things a little bit more complicated as I agree that they do not make much sense as outcome for an exponential formula.